# Reference for a version of the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem for $L^1$ space into $BV$ space

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a note about  [Modica-Mortola Functional](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Etblass/CNA-PIRE/Leoni_modica-mortola-lecture-2012-02-17.pdf).
On page3, the author claims that by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem, for a bounded sequence $(u_n)\subset L^1(\Omega)$, we can find a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ and a $u\in BV(\Omega)$ such that
$$u_{n_k}\to u\mbox{ in }L_{loc}^{1}(\Omega).$$
Since the version of the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem I know is to compactly embede Sobolev spaces into some $L^p$ spaces, so I'm wondering if anyone can give any reference about this version.
Any clue would be welcome!

Comment: There is also a version of that theorem for BV functions. I suspect your sequence to be bounded in BV

Comment: @daw, I think in that proof, we can not get the boundedness of the (weak) derivative term, since the bound on the energy term can only imply $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_{n}|\leq C\cdot \epsilon_{n}$ with $\epsilon_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.